# Boost python extract module name during compilation

Tags: python, c++, boost, makefile

What is the best way to extract the name of the boost module I'm compiling from the Makefile? I'm afraid I might have to practically write a crude C compiler in order to effectively extract it with pattern matching.

The basic hard-coded version I have is this (I haven't tested it. I'm just using it as an example):

```
SOURCES=test.cpp boost_features.cpp util.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
# Extract module name here \/\/\/
LIB=$(patsubst ') {',,$(patsubst 'BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(',,$($(shell grep 'BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(*) {' $(SOURCES)))))
CFLAGS=-fPIC -Wall

.PHONY: clean

$(LIB): $(OBJECTS)
        g++ -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS) -I/usr/include/python2.6 -lboost_python -lpython2.6 $(CFLAGS)
        @echo Done compiling!

boost_features.o: util.h

$(OBJECTS): %.o : %.cpp
        g++ -c $< -o $@ -I/usr/include/python2.6 -lboost_python -lpython2.6 $(CFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(LIB)
```